# What's the male version of "hottie"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

According to Google:

> **hottie**
>
> a sexually attractive person, especially a young woman.

What's the male version of the word? Or it is also used in men?

Example:

> "Who's that hottie?" I asked Anna, pointing at the man across the
>   pool.

Comment: Yes, it is also used for men (the word "especially" in this definition implies that it is not exclusively used for young women). You should describe more specifically what kind of word you want, and in what situation it would be used.

Comment: @sumelic I added an example.

Comment: Wait, women can be hotties, too? I never knew that!

Comment: Mine's a pint of bitter and a hot tottie on the side!

Comment: https://media0ch-a.akamaihd.net/58/53/98a2eb703cd33ba1897027d74dbeada6.jpg

Comment: When I saw the question title, my first thought was of a woman using it to describe a man, and I wondered if you maybe the question was actually asking for a less female-speaker-coded word. So yes, it is used for men.

Comment: I would say Beefcake

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Merriam-Webster has a gender-free definition of "[hottie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hottie):"

> a physically attractive person.

A quick Google search on ["he's a hottie"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on#q=%22he%27s%20a%20hottie%22&safe=active&ssui=on) yields many results.

Comment: It's fascinating that these answers have generated so much interest. I would be very curious to know whether men feel that "hottie," since it has what barely counts in English as a diminutive suffix, feels less comfortable than "hunk" or "stud," both of which imply a sense of "manliness" that "hottie" does not, since "hottie" is more general about attractiveness.

Comment: I would prefer to be called a stud. But I'm older; perhaps hottie has become more gender neutral these days.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood, (1) "-ie" is often more affectionate than strictly diminutive, e.g. "sweetie" or "dearie" (2) IDK about comfort, but in addition to being specifically masculine, "hunk" and "stud" do not imply the same level of affection that "hottie" does. "He's a stud" could be said by straight man; "He's a hottie" probably wouldn't.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood In addition to what Paul Draper said, I think it also depends on how the person looks. A person can be a hunk and a hottie, but some people are just [hotties, not hunks](https://www.google.com.tw/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com%2F564x%2F1e%2Fb2%2F35%2F1eb235553eb6f92cd610c07eacb72e01.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Ffrancisnz%2Fmy-style%2F&docid=oFoS8PVM5lyguM&tbnid=WrFNUKAdTTP7zM%3A&vet=1&w=500&h=700&client=firefox-b-ab&bih=791&biw=1440&q=thin%20male%20hottie&ved=0ahUKEwizrumIgbXRAhXHGZQKHSrUDa4QMwgnKA0wDQ&iact=mrc&uact=8).

Comment: It was good enough for *The West Wing*, one of the most popular and award-winning television shows in recent history. In the episode “365 Days,” Annabeth Schott suggests to the First Lady that “the hotties” are the reason that NASCAR is unusually popular with women, and then proceeds to show off pictures of several male drivers.

Comment: Never having ever been referred to as a hottie, a hunk, or a stud, I'd have to say they all sound equally ridiculous to me....

Answer (score 70):

Hunk is probably the word you are looking for

As per Collins dictionary, the definition of hunk is "a well-built, sexually attractive man"

Comment: I don't think this is a direct match. Unlike a "hunk", I don't think a "hottie" has to be "well built" (which I interpret to mean muscular). But sexually attractive, yes.

Comment: @ColinMackay There probably isn't an "exact match" because the traits that are generally considered attractive in men and women are not the same.

Comment: @Casey Even when referring to men as viewed by women, though, they aren't really an exact match. As Katherine's answer points out, "hottie" normally just means "physically attractive" without implying which particular features were found attractive.

Comment: @reirab It's pretty unusual for a man to be considered physically attractive if he has a poor physique. He doesn't have to be overly muscular, but he shouldn't be flabby.

Comment: @Barmar True, but, at least in my (AmE) experience, females tend to use 'hunk' to mean "overly muscular," while 'hottie' is a broader term which includes that, but also includes the "not overly muscular, but also not flabby" crowd that you mention. This is not to say that there are no counter-example uses, just that the difference in usage seems to be enough for the words to have somewhat different connotations.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. Maybe it depends on the context. In the gym, where you can see everyone's body, only the muscular ones would be called hunks. In a bar, any really attractive man might be a hunk.

Answer (score 32):

I would suggest using word *stud*, but it gives quite a virile connotation. Citing [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stud) 3,

> **Stud**: [...] a young man: guy; especially: one who is virile and promiscuous.

Comment: Don't think this is right. Hotties are not necessarily promiscuous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As a native speaker, I mostly heard *stud* referring to attractive, muscular guys, not necessarily implying promiscuity.

Comment: To be fair, so have I. But I'm going off what you cited :)

Answer (score 14):

A specifically male version of *hottie* would be *dreamboat*.

The term *fox* is usually used in reference to a male, while *foxy* is the female version.

The term *dish* or *dishy* is most often used in reference to a male.

Each of these terms has been in use for some time and therefore may appear to be a bit dated today.

Comment: Definitely a bit dated :)

Comment: "foxy" as the female version? Maybe, but you could also use "vixen" (which is literally a female fox). Also, I'd say "fox" applies more to older men.

Comment: @ColinMackay - An older man is a "silver fox". The "silver" referring to hair colour, and thus the part that denotes "older".

Comment: The main difference between *fox* and *foxy* is that one is a noun and the other is an adjective. *Fox* can refer to men, but both are used to refer to women, or at least were when the terms were actually in common use. Even half a century ago The Doors had a song about a woman called "Twentieth Century Fox."

Comment: @JustinLardinois Fair enough.  I was thinking more of "Foxy Lady" by Jimi Hendrix.  I've never heard a woman referred to as a fox, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: When I was in high school (a long long time ago), there was a woman in our class whose last name was *Fox*. And we thought that name suited her well...

Comment: @ColinMackay vixen is wrong. When a woman is "foxy", it has a sexual/attractive connotation. A "vixen" however is vicious and mean. It is basically the same as calling her a "bitch".

Comment: @A.Levy I can't agree. I've seen several men's magazines describe a "sexy" woman as a vixen (although that was a while ago, perhaps the meaning has changed over the last 20 years)

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vixen (Def. 3): (colloquial) A racy or salacious woman.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vixen (Def. 3) a sexually attractive woman

Answer (score 10):

(as others have stated) Hottie is not gender specific. However, if you wanted a more male specific version, stud might apply (however this is more antiquated)

Answer (score 2):

Since 'hottie' is not particularly powerful or vulgar (as I perceive it anyway), and since it's not gender-specific but used to describe women more than men - I would consider **heartthrob** - also not gender-specific, but IIRC used to describe men more than it does women.

Comment: I would say _heartthrob_ carries more of an emotional nuance that isn't present in _hottie_ (which to my mind is more about physical attractiveness).

Comment: I'd say that a heartthrob is necessarily a celebrity.

Answer (score 0):

[This search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%27s%20a%20hottie%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) shows that "hottie" is also used for men.