# What is the meaning of the term "town hottie"?

Tags: phrases, terminology, phrase-meaning

I know I heard this term several times before, but when I look it up, I can't find anything on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up “hottie”

Comment: Must be a pretty small town if there's only one seriously attractive young woman there.

Comment: @BoldBen Smurf Village!

Comment: @BoldBen: "Best" does not mean the same thing as "only". Though I have seen some towns where it does.

Comment: @Flater I had no idea that "Town Hottie" was graded in that way. It's not a British term.

Comment: @Flater I would understand _town/village X_ to refer (perhaps not entirely accurately, but notionally at least) to the **only** X in the town/village. The village idiot is the one person in the village everyone considers an idiot, and the town hottie would be the one person in town everyone considers a hottie – in other words, a very small town indeed!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Traits are usually a spectrum, not a binary state. It makes little sense for only one person to be considered attractive, in _any_ size of community. Tastes differ and not everyone will agree on who is more attractive than who. But the town hottie is _predominantly_ agreed to be _predominantly_  the most attractive. The same applies to drunk/idiot. You can argue anyone who is drunk at one point to be a drunk. The town drunk isn't necessarily _always_ drunk, but he is the person who is _most often_ drunk, on the spectrum of alcohol drinkers. And similar for idiocy.

Answer (score 2):

The generalized "town [description]" effectively means "the person who is the biggest/best [description] in their/my town". Examples:

- [Town drunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_drunk), i.e. the person in a town who is known to be a drunkard.
- [Village idiot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Village_idiot), i.e. the biggest (well-known) idiot in the village.

[Hottie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hottie) simply means "an attractive person" (most commonly a woman, [but not exclusively so](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366856/whats-the-male-version-of-hottie)).

"Town hottie" therefore means:

> The most attractive person in their/my town.

Comment: Oh, so you have heard hottie for men?

Comment: @Lambie: Yes. But only in a minority of cases. Without further context, I'm inclined to assume it's referring to a female; but that's not the same as saying that it _can't_ refer to a man.

Comment: Regardless of how, it's definitely distaff.

Comment: @Lambie [Counterpoint, with link to results for the male use case](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366856/whats-the-male-version-of-hottie)

Comment: I would look twice is someone used that for a guy.

Comment: @Lambie Are you a straight male? Not to imply anything, I (as a straight male) wouldn't use it either. But my wife does use it, and so does my gay male friend. Because it makes more sense for them to refer to men as "hot".

Comment: Speaking personally, I've more frequently heard women refer to young men as *hotties* than I've heard men refer to women with that word.

Comment: @Lambie I have seen and heard _hottie_ used for men quite literally thousands of times, and done so myself quite frequently too. It is exceedingly common, to the point that when I read the title of the question, I automatically understood it to refer to a man until I read BoldBen’s comment. It is definitely **not** distaff. I agree entirely with Jason here.